# Noise when playing sound repeatedly tapping a button in iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, noise

I have a view with a button (or sub view) that you can tap to play a sound. It sounds fine but if you tap the button quickly repeatedly then a popping/crackling noise sounds at the beginning of the sound being played. This happens on the device and on the simulator.

Here is a sample code of what is executed when the button is tapped:

```
if([self.playerTest isPlaying]) [self.playerTest stop];//I tried with this line and without it. No difference.
NSError *error;
self.playerTest = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
[self.playerTest prepareToPlay];
[self.playerTest play];
```

I tried doing it this way as well and same result:

```
//This is executed on the init
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
[self.audioPlayerEngine attachNode:self.player];

//This is called when the button is tapped
if([self.player isPlaying]) [self.player stop];//I tried with this line and without it. No difference.
NSError *error;
AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:soundFile error:&error];
AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = [self.audioPlayerEngine mainMixerNode];
[self.audioPlayerEngine connect:self.player to:mainMixer format:file.processingFormat];
[self.player scheduleFile:file atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
[self.audioPlayerEngine startAndReturnError:nil];
[self.player play];
```

I tried in all cases stopping the sound before playing the next

I tried with different sound files and different formats (wav, caf, mp3). I have also tried using OpenAL. OpenAL works fine in IOS 8 but in IOS 9 you get the noises as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is happened buz you are playing sound multiple  time by clcik onthe button quickly .

Comment: I know and that is what I am trying to achieve. You could suppose that the button is a drum pad trigger or a piano key. It has to sound well no matter how fast you tap on it.

Comment: Btw, I also tried stoping the player if there is anything playing just before taking care of the current button tap to make sure there is only one sound playing simultaneously although I think that is how it works by default.